# Not able to list data in descending order in bootstrap datatable

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, datatable

I am using codeigniter for build back end of my site and bootstrap admin panel for UI. 
My issue is that i am not able to display data table list in descending order. data table always list in ascending order of the first column.
This is the query i used

```
 public function listevents()
    {       $this->db->order_by("id", "desc");
        $query=$this->db->get('events');
        return $query->result_array();

    }
```

i am using bootstrap datatables to display my result
[Bootstrap datatable demo link](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html)

Comment: Your function is working fine

Comment: Your query is returning in desc order, maybe the issue is something else ?

Comment: Yeah query works fine in normal html table. But when i am using bootstrap datatable it dosent works.

Comment: So you should post your other code not just the query because the issue is not in your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is correct only.you need to customize your bootstrap library.because bootstrap datatable default order is asending.u need to change the library is.
    $(document).ready( function() {
      $('#example').dataTable( {
        "order": [[0,'asc']]
      });
    });
Here example is ur table name and 0 is ur id index in the table

Answer (score 0):

Use this It may work.

```
 public function listevents()
    {      
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('events');
        $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```